# clearInterval() is not stopping setInterval() - Firefox Extension Development

Tags: javascript, checkbox, firefox-addon, xul, setinterval

I am working on a modification of tamper data that will allow me to send the HTTP request/responses it observes to a server. So far, that functionality has been implemented correctly. The next step is to automate this process, and I wish to use a toolbarmenu button of type 'checkbox' to toggle this functionality on and off.

So far I have this bit of code in the .XUL:

```
<toolbarbutton id="tamper.autosend" label="&tamper.toolbar.autosend;" type="checkbox" oncommand="oTamper.toggleTimer();"/>
```

And this function in the main driver of my extension:

```
toggleTimer : function() {
 var checked = document.getElementById('tamper.autosend').checked;

 var consoleService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/consoleservice;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIConsoleService);

 consoleService.logStringMessage(checked);

 if (checked) {
        var interval = window.setInterval(function(thisObj) { thisObj.sendResults(true); }, 1000, this);
 }

 else {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
 }
}
```

Using the consoleService I see that the value of 'checked' is indeed correct. I believe the problem lies with how I am calling clearInterval, but I'm not exactly sure how to remedy it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have defined interval inside if try to declare your variable on the start

```
var interval = 0;
toggleTimer : function() {
 var checked = document.getElementById('tamper.autosend').checked;

 var consoleService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/consoleservice;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIConsoleService);

 consoleService.logStringMessage(checked);

 if (checked) {
        interval = window.setInterval(function(thisObj) { thisObj.sendResults(true); }, 1000, this);
 }

 else {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
 }
}
```

Comment: It's good to avoid globals whenever possible. Store it in oTamper.interval instead.

Comment: Hungarian notation is pretty widely discouraged at this point in time.

Answer (score 5):

Your doing it wrong, each time you want to set the new interval you should clear it first

```
clearInterval(intervalID);

console.log('reset timer');

intervalID = setInterval(function () {
    console.log('tick');
}, refreshInterval);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're storing the `interval` in a local variable; the value is lost after the function returns, next time you attempt to `clearInterval` an undefined variable. Store the interval in i.e. a global variable instead:

```
 if (checked) {
        window.interval = window.setInterval(function(thisObj) { thisObj.sendResults(true); }, 1000, this);
 }

 else {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse, because `interval` is defined as a private variable. It is defined in the `toggleTimer` function and is destroyed when the function ends.

Use `interval = window.setInterval()` instead of `var interval = window.setInterval()` to define a global variable that is accessible later for `clearInterval`.

Below are some examples of the JavaScript variable scope. `var` is used to define a variable in the *current* scope. Leaving `var` always creates or changes a local variable.

```
function func1() {
    i = 1; // global
}
func1();
alert(i); // 1

var j = 2;
function func2() {
    var j = 3; // private
}
func2();
alert(j); // 2

k = 4;
function func3() {
    k = 5; // global
}
func3();
alert(k); // 5

var l = 6;
function func4() {
    l = 7; // global
}
func4();
alert(l); // 7

function func5() {
    var m = 6; // private
}
func5();
alert(m); // undefined
```